# How do I get City from an museum entity in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to retrieve the city where a museum is located in. However, for museums in Manhattan, I should be retrieving New York City instead. Currently I am pulling on P131 (administrative territorial), is there any other way I can get the city? I've tried pulling on P131 twice, but for proper cities (i.e. Berlin), their P131 is usually the country name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city WHERE {
      #fiter condition
      ?item wdt:P276 ?museum.
      ?museum wdt:P131 ?cityCode.
      ?cityCode rdfs:label ?city.
  FILTER(lang(?city) = "en") 
}
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?city WHERE {
      VALUES ?museum {wd:Q188740}
     
      ?museum wdt:P131* ?cityCode. ?cityCode wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 .
      ?cityCode rdfs:label ?city.
  FILTER(lang(?city) = "en") 
}`

Comment: thanks! it worked, however some museums i queried did not have a city turn up, I believe it could be due to some issues with their P131 values